# Deviance residual for binomial regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, deviance

The deviance residual for binomial regression has the form $sign(y_i- m_i\hat{p}_i)d_i$, where $m_i\hat{p}_i$ is the fitted value, $d_i$ is the contribution of observation i to the deviance of the model fitted. I am having some troubles deriving the form of $d_i$. As shown below, I could not obtain the coefficient for the 2nd log term to be $m_i-y_i$. Could anyone show me where I made mistakes? Thanks in advance!

The form given in my lecture notes:
[image]

My attempt of derivation:
[image]

---

As mentioned by Thomas, the natural parameter $\theta_i$ = logit($\mu_i$) instead. The correct derivation:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check: who's wrong?

Your version breaks down if $y_i=m_i$ but $\hat p_i\neq 1$, giving $m_i\log 0=-\infty$ for the second term and no rescue from the first term, which stays finite. The version in  your notes is ok if you define $x\log x$ at $x=0$ by the limit from above.

Tracing that back, infinities first appear at your  second  bullet point.

Even before that, though, you've taken the parameter to be $\log \mu$ and it's actually $\mathrm{logit} \mu$ (assuming you're using the canonical logit link, which matches the formula in your lecture notes).